# Ceiling Fan Not Working

Tags: electrical

In one of my rooms a ceiling fan stopped working.  We replaced it with a brand new one but still no luck.  It is getting power in the attic and when we tested the wall switch it has power when switched off at the wall but when we turn the switch on it has no power registered.  The bedroom right next to it is now also having the same issue.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You mean that the fan in the next room now also has stopped working?

Comment: Is power run to the fan box first, or to the switch box first?  Also, how are you testing for the presence of power?